# MVC: User Verification

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a simple mvc app where I would like to verify the user's login for each page load.  Even though it's a session based login, I would still like to verify the information to be on the safe side.

My question is where should the verify user function go?  Should it go in a controller that executes before the user requested controller?

Comment: have you tried anything? consider posting you code sample.

Comment: yes, access control is typically done during the bootstrap process using a dedicated controller

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "to be on the safe side, I would like to verify the information each time."  *What* "information," beyond the session-token, do you intend to "verify?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean by "to be on the safe side, I would like to verify the information each time."  *What* "information," beyond the session-token, do you intend to "verify?"  This should be superfluous:  if the user gives a token that you recognize, say, to be from the IP-address that you issued it to, no further verification should be required.

As to the second question, there are always going to be, shall we say, "a few necessary preliminaries" in any MVC application:  getting the URL string (and any GET/POST parameters), making sure they're as-expected, and, yes, validating the session-token to be sure *(a)* that it is valid, and *(b)* that the thus-identified user is authorized to make this request.  If this is not so, the request can be dumped out with a `403 Forbidden` or similar response:  there's no reason to proceed further.

Therefore, if and when a "real" controller *does* get handed a request, it can take for granted that the request is (apparently) well-formed and that it is authorized.  (Or, at least, *authenticated:* the requestor, at this point, "has a verified and trustworthy identity.")

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was thinking it was best to verify the season information each page load but realize that might be overkill.

Comment: You *definitely* should carefully-verify the token.  You should pay attention to cross-side request forgery (CSRF) and "all the usual suspects."  But, if the incoming requests presents a verifiable token *and* is otherwise consistent with *e-v-e-r-y-t-h-i-n-g* that you know about "whomever you [recently] issued it to," that should be enough.